# Cross-browser centering with scaling element

Tags: css, centering

I'm using this method to center box on screen:

```
#container {
        position:fixed;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        top:50%;
        left:50%;
        margin-top:-50%;
        margin-left:-50%;
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
        -ms-transform: scale(0.8);
        -o-transform: scale(0.8);
        transform: scale(0.8);
    }
```

(I need the scaling for certain functionality)

It work in Safari but breaks in vertical alignment in Chrome and Firefox. Is there a similar method that works cross-browser?

Comment: If the box is `width` and `height` `100%`, what difference does it make if it is centered?

Comment: it matters for the scaling part, I'm scaling to 100% to match window size but scaling to 80% for a certain purpose. anyway, I rewrote that part... see below

Comment: ...I'm in noob mode here, can't answer my own question. I edited the original question...

Answer (score 0):

This is how I resolved it:

I rewrote the box sizing of 100% via jQuery. Once specific size is set to the box, it seems to work in FF and Chrome.

I got around the unwanted transformation when page first loads by applying the transforms on the fly only when required. ...Unless there's a cleaner way to get callBack from transformation completed?

Sample: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7782299/sample/zoom2.html

Here's full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="support/CSSreset.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">

    <style>

    body {
        background:red;
        overflow:hidden;
    }

    #container {
        position:fixed;
        top:50%;
        left:50%;
        background:blue;
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
        -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
    }
        #container.preon {
            -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        }

        #container.on {
            -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            -moz-transform: scale(1);
        }

    </style>

    <script src="support/jquery-2.0.3.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready( function() {

        $('#container').click(function() {

            $('#container').addClass('preon');
            $('#container').toggleClass('on');
            setTimeout( function() { $('#container').removeClass('preon'); }, 600);

        });

        placeContainer = function placeContainer() {

            $('#container').css({
                width: $(window).width() + "px",
                height: $(window).height() + "px",
                marginLeft: (($(window).width())/2)*-1,
                marginTop: (($(window).height())/2)*-1
            });

        };

        placeContainer();

    });

    $(window).resize(function() {

        placeContainer();

    });

    $(window).trigger('resize');

    </script>


</head>
<body>

    <div id="container"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I edited this post to move the answer to its own reply (i.e. removed prior edits to the original question)